# Why cant i see the verices on this mesh?

Tags: objects, edit-mode, vertices

So as you can probably see i have been following this tutorial on how to make a donut in blender since i am new to the program. It all worked fine until i suddenly could'nt use the weight brush on the top half of the donut (the icing), which i found out was caused by the fact that only the edges were editable, since it would only let me use the brush there. Really hoping someone can help.[image]

Comment: I think you've hidden the edges in the icing mesh. Select the icing, enter edit mode with Tab, and press Alt+H to unhide.

Comment: Thank you so much, really saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Object Mode always displays the entire mesh, even if you have parts or the entire mesh/vertices/edges/faces hidden by using <kbd>H</kbd>.

So coming back later in object mode and switching in edit mode to find that parts are missing/not displayed, is solved by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, which brings everything hidden back.